# Why is my set cell height in Interface Builder not actually becoming the height in the app/simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder, storyboard

I set it to 95px in the storyboard. (Under size inspector)

[image]

But it ends up looking like this in the simulator (all squished):

[image]

I don't know what else to show. I don't know what's causing it. No, I don't define the height in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the *table* that determines the cell height (with its `rowHeight` property).

The cell height in the nib/storyboard is just a sandbox for you to design in; the cell will be resized at runtime in accordance with the table's `rowHeight` (or the delegate's `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` if implemented).

That is why everything in the cell needs to have good autoresizing or constraints; the cell can be resized on its way into the table view.